# How to add reference to another relation for postgres list data type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In `postgres` database, I have two relations, `student` and `project`. For student relation, I have studentid as a primary key. In project relation, I want to add a list of student ids as a foreign key. I am writing the query like this:

`CREATE TABLE project(projectid varchar(36), name text, participants varchar[] REFERENCES student(studentid));`

It gives me an error:

`Key columns "participants" and "studentid" are of incompatible types varying[] and character varying`

How do I refer each individual in a list as a reference to other relation in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

The participant relationship between projects and students is not an attribute of project (nor is it an attribute of student). The relationship should be modeled as an associative table linking project and student:

```
CREATE TABLE projects_students(
  projectid varchar(36) REFERENCES project(projectid),
  studentid varchar(36) REFERENCES student(studentid),
  CONSTRAINT projects_students_pk PRIMARY KEY (projectid, studentid)
);
CREATE INDEX students_projects_ndx ON projects_students(studentid);
```

There are several issues with storing participants as an array attribute of project. Two of them are difficulty maintaining referential integrity, and identifying for which projects a student is a participant. Both of these issues are addressed by using an associative table with appropriate foreign key constraints and indexes.